# How to find coeficients in power function?

Tags: r

I'm working with LTV prediction and stuck with a problem.

I need to solve power equation: `a*x**b = y`, where `x` and `y` are variables, of which I know the first 30, but `a` and `b` are constants, which I don't know.

Task is to find `a` and `b` such that predicted `y` will have the smallest square deviation from known.

At this moment I find only a solution on Excel.

```
A=EXP(INDEX(LINEST(LN(Known Ys), LN(Known Xs)), 2))
B=INDEX(LINEST(LN(Known Ys), LN(Known Xs)), 1)
```

Comment: can you pleas include a sample of your data (using `dput(head(data, 20))`) and any code that you have tried? Also please include the expected output for the data you include in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R this should be something like

```
## fit a log-log model and extract coefficients
cc <- coef(lm(log(y) ~ log(x)))
## the slope of the log-log model is the exponent
b <- cc[["y"]]
## exp(intercept) is the multiplicative coefficient
a <- exp(cc[["(Intercept)"]])
```

Note that these solutions minimize the squared error *on the log scale*: if you want to minimize the squared error on the linear scale, you need to fit

```
glm(y~log(x), family=gaussian(link="log"))
```

and then extract its coefficients etc.